# What is the best octal permission for a config.php file?

Tags: php, linux, permissions, cpanel

So let's say that I have a LAMP stack project hosted on a Linux server with cPanel on it with only one user. What is the permissions that I'm supposed to set to a file with passwords and API keys being set on it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best permissions for you will be 644. It means that the owner (user, who will deploy the code) has read and write permissions, the group and other users have only read permission. If your user is in the same group as web-server user (www-data, apache2, etc.) and the file is owned by this group, you can reduce permissions to 640, with this config all other users have no rights to read/write/execute the file.

Comment: Thank you that sounds good. I have a separate issue with my webpage. Basically as Javscript is calling the config.php file but it can't find it.

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ script.js:73`

And this is the line that calls the PHP file on the server:
`fetch("config.php")
...
`

Comment: Nevermind this issue had nothing to do with permissions it's missing a PHP code to echo the public key

Comment: I disagree. Sensitive info should not be world and group readable. 644 is for sure not "best"

Comment: It is not generally true. You missed that TS has access via CPanel and your advice is based on assumptions that the TS has access to ssh and acl is installed on the server. So, you have at least one user (user on behalf of webserver run and you are not this user) and this user should have access to the config. 640 (or 644 if user not in the www-data group) will be enough. If we are talking about the security aspect: yes, using acl will be more secure, but also it is not the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

It should be 0600, which means only the owner can read and write. If other accounts than the owner need to read it use setfacl.

```
setfacl -m u:other:rwx
```

Or

```
setfacl -m u:other:r
```

Generally speaking you don't want sensitive info to be readable by others.

Comment: It is not generally true. You missed that TS has access via CPanel and your advice is based on assumptions that the TS has access to ssh and acl is installed on the server. So, you have at least one user (user on behalf of webserver run and you are not this user) and this user should have access to the config. 640 (or 644 if user not in the www-data group) will be enough. If we are talking about the security aspect: yes, using acl will be more secure, but also it is not the best choice.